# Run PHP pages without an extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to run my PHP web pages on an apache web server without the `.php` extension. So I added the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/?.*\..*$) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php [NC]
```

in the `.htaccess` file. This solves my problem but another problem arises. I cannot view the content of any directory (i.e. the file contained in the directory). Please provide me an alternate `RewriteRule` without this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that the request URI points to an existing resource if you append the.php to the end of it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/?.*\..*$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php [NC]
```

the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` checks if a ".php" is appended to the requested URI, it mapes to an existing file (`-f`).

Comment: Thanks for quick response and solving my problem,

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code, it is working on my website:

```
RewriteEngine On
#unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

#redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
#RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [`DirectoryIndex`](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/directoryindex-uses/) above your `RewriteCond`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```