# Custom URL to point to php file

Tags: php, url

How do I point a URL to a file so when I go to the URL it points to that file but doesn't change the URL. For example:
mydomain.com/orders/create should point to /myfiles/orders-create.php

then when I go to mydomain.com/orders/create it will display all the contents of orders-create.php.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Yes that showed the HTML content but none of the styling that is on a PHP include. Showing a 404 error for all the css and image files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on the server-side you could edit the `.htaccess` file similar to [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624639/run-php-pages-without-an-extension).

The main changes you're looking at are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php [NC]
```

This would let you create files without an extension and it would run force run the PHP interpreter.

Here's a good read for [pretty URLs](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049) to find out more ways you could do this, and it'll explain more about what they actually are.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change `create-order.php`, then you can make it so that it does not rely on relative paths. One way to do this is to create a `bootstrap.php` file that has all of the includes and then your "leaf" PHP files only have to find this `bootstrap.php` file.

Another option is to set the PHP path. If you change the include path to include the root of the directory, then when including files in `create-order.php` will look in the root and it will find them. You can set the include path in your [PHP files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) or in the PHP configuration.

If you don't want or can't change `create-order.php` then one way to do this would be via the webserver. For example, in apache, you can use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do just that, have a public URL actually invoke a specific local file. The rewrite configuration might look like this (example for just this one file):

```sh
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteRule ^orders/create to create-order.php$ create-order.php [L]
```

or a catch-all rule with this (untested):

```
RewriteRule ^orders/(.*)$   $1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: I've just updated my post, would that RewriteRule do what I need?

Comment: I've added a catch-all query, haven't tried it myself so it might need tweaks.